# How to get the form choice field values?

Tags: python, django

[[image]`Form._bound_fields_cache['limit'].field.choices[var][1]`

I want to get the `[][1]` this value from each choice field how to get it.

**I tried as above**

where choice is need to be iterated but i am not getting it.

and need to append values in dictionary to it.

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension if you need a list.
something like this:

```
[choice[1] for choice in Form._bound_fields_cache['limit'].field.choices]
```

or a more readable for loop:

```
choice_values = list()
for choice in Form._bound_fields_cache['limit'].field.choices:
    choice_values.append(choice[1])
```

Comment: I have dict , i want to append the values to the choice[1]

Comment: @KaranKapadni You should try to clarify your original question with adding extra info. You have a dict, so you have keys and value pairs, what do you want to add to the choices? Can you show the code of your form? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `for choice in Form._bound_fields_cache['limit'].field.choices:
KeyError: 'limit'`

Comment: Can you update your initial question with the info I asked you about. It is hard to properly help if we have almost no info. Apparently the field ['limit'] doesn't exist.

Comment: So the current choices don't need to change, you just want to add extra choices to it? And you have a dict with key value pairs that you want to add (append) to the current list with choices?